# In Cantonese, what does 多到 (do1 dou3) mean?

Tags: cantonese

In Cantonese, what does 多到 (do1 dou3) mean in this context?

> 你可以想像罪案**多到**幾咁嚴重嘞!
>
> nei5 ho2-ji5 soeng2-zoeng6 zeoi6-on3 **do1 dou3** gei2-gam3 jim4-zung6 laak3!

My guess is that the sentence translates to something like this:

> You can imagine the criminal cases — **many became** quite serious!

But I'm really not sure.  This is the first time I've come across this pattern.

Comment: 多到數唔晒 = Ample amount (So many that I can't even count them all.)

Comment: "想像" here is more like "guess"/"conjecture" than "imagine".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can understand it as "so many that...":

> You can imagine the criminal cases are **so many that** the situation is serious.

Comment: This is correct. It says that the number of cases are 多 (many) 到 (to the extent that) it's getting serious.

Answer (score 0):

"多到幾咁嚴重" is sometimes simply a verbal form of "嚴重地多"

In such context, you can translate the sentence as:

You can conjecture that the number of criminal cases is seriously high.